# $\sum \cos(2n)$ Is upper bounded

Tags: real-analysis

Proof that $\sum \cos(2n)$ where $n = 1, 2, 3, ...$ is upper bounded. Is ther an easier way than using Moivre's formula? I did try that and failed with complex part.

Comment: The de Moivre formula approach seems reasonably simple, we get two geometric series. Sum them and use the Triangle Inequality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use induction to show that
$$\sum_{n=1}^m \cos(2n) = \dfrac{\sin(n)\cos(n+1)}{\sin(1)}$$
Now can you see why this is bounded?

Comment: That's a neat identity. How did you find it?

Comment: Of course you meant $m$ on the right side, not $n$.